# "The application does not have the cloud notification capability" on xbox live sign in on unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, xbox-live

Whenever I try to sign into Xbox Live on my Unity game (using creators program Unity plugin), both on UWP PC and Xbox One, the game throws an exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAEF0AA899 in Boulder Falls.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x000000E51B6FEC20. HRESULT:0x803E0110 The application does not have the cloud notification capability.
WinRT information: The application does not have the cloud notification capability.
Stack trace:
 >[External Code]
The program '[5896] Boulder Falls.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).]
```

I am using the included prefab to sign in, and I do have developer mode enabled on both the PC and the Xbox, they are all in the correct sandbox, XboxServices.config has XboxLiveCreatorsTitle set to true, and the account I am using is in the test account list. Is there any solution to this?

Edit:
If I try to continue past the exception, it throws another one:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA7F1BA839 in Boulder Falls.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::AccessDeniedException ^ at memory location 0x000000D2BA3FE740. HRESULT:0x80070005 Access is denied.
WinRT information: A network capability is required to access this network resource occurred
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I just rebuilt the program in a new folder from Unity, and compiled it from Visual Studio 2017 instead of 2019.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue, too.  For us it turned out to be setting the "InternetClient" capability in the Unity PlayerSettings.  However, even after checking that, we had to delete the existing build folder because Unity wouldn't update the existing files with the new capability.  For reference, there's a quick mention of setting the capability (step 10):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/get-started/setup-ide/managed-partners/unity-win10/live-partner-unity-uwp-il2cpp